# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (7942, 1)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, valueerror

I have been using the following functional API for an image classification task using CNN:

```
def create_model(X_train, X_test):

    visible = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible)
    hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pool2)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)

    model = Model(inputs = visible, outputs = output)

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

X_tr = np.reshape(X_train, (1,X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_te = np.reshape(X_test, (1,X_test.shape[0],  X_test.shape[1], 1))

model = create_model(X_train, X_test)

model.fit(X_tr, y_train, validation_split = 0.1, batch_size=10, epochs=10, verbose = 1, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=5,verbose=1)])
```

where, `X_train` is a 7942*6400 dimensional list and `y_train` being a 1-D list with corresponding 7942 labels.

The error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (7942, 1)

What has possibly gone wrong here as I am a newbie to the functional API?

Comment: If `X_train` contains images, how are the 6400 values distributed in the image? What is height, width and channels?

Comment: I am reading the feature values from a csv file; each row of which contains 6400 pixels and their corresponding labels; so that, the (height, width, channels) I am considering are (1, 6400, 1).

Comment: This is not going to work. If they're images they're 2D, something such as (800,800,1).

Comment: Yes, they are originally 80x80 images but I have listed all the pixel intensity values in the form of 1-D arrays in the csv file. Will that still not work?

Answer (score 4):

The message says that `y_train` is not compatible with the model's output.

Your model is outputting `(None, width, height, 1)`. You should add a `Flatten()` layer after the convolution to make the data have only 2 dimensions from this point on.

---

Additional comments:

The input data must have a shape compatible with the model.

The shape of `X_train` must be `(7942,80,80,1)`
The  `input_shape` of the model must be `(80,80,1)`

If you use a `(1,6400, 1)` shape, your `Conv2D` layer will be pretty useless, because it will not be able to intepret the data as a 2D image.